# View CIL of C# code on Linux with mono

Tags: c#, linux, mono, cil

I want to inspect the generated [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) code of the following C# source file on Linux:

```
using System;
namespace PrintPrimes
{
    class Algorithm
    {
        static bool IsPrime(int p)
        {
            for (int i=2;i<p;i++)
            {
                for (int j=i;j<p;j++)
                {
                    if (i*j == p)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        static void Main() 
        {
            for (int p=2;p<=20;p++)
            {
                if (IsPrime(p))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p + " ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile and run it everything is fine:

```
$ mcs -out:PrintPrimes PrintPrimes.cs
$ ./PrintPrimes
2 
3 
5 
7 
11 
13 
17 
19
```

But how can I get the human readable CIL output?

Comment: Mono, Dis/Assembling CIL Code:  https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/monodis/

Comment: @AlexF thanks: `monodis --output=PrintPrimes.cil PrintPrimes` works! if you post it as an answer I can easily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono disassembler, extracts IL code from an assembly:

```
monodis FILE-name
```

Full reference can be found here:
https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/monodis/

Dis/Assembling CIL Code  (Mono Project)

Comment: `ikdasm` is newer.